# Archive submission failed due to the issue listed below. ERROR ITMS-90039

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I am getting error while uploading my app to appstore from xcode.

"type mismatch. the value for the info.plist key UILaunchImageName is not of the required type for that key."

I am getting this error after updating xcode 7

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: I just had a similar issue with UIFileSharingEnabled, which was set to YES and had always worked. The solution was to change the type to Boolean -- which is what it's supposed to be -- and the whole thing continues to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by removing googlemaps framework references from my project and adding again by cocoapods [use this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the UILaunchImages entry from the info.plist file. I know it's not a proper solution rather just a hack, but I needed to upload my build urgently and only this seemed to work.